# Flurdy email server guide: sending mail through client not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email-server, email

I have set up a mail server using the well-known [flurdy guide](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/#test). I installed the mail server on my dedicated ubuntu server 9.04 which also runs my web sites. After lots of issues I have gotten the mail server to work so that email accounts can receive email; I have checked this using outlook and squirrelmail.

Now, while i can SEND email through squirrelmail, **I cannot get email clients (outlook, iphone, etc) to do the same. So they can connect to the mail server and receive new email but nothing goes out.**

Because squirrelmail is able to send email on the server, I suspect there is a issue related to firewall, ports, encryption, etc, but i honestly don't know where to begin troubleshooting. I can, however, tell that my hosting provider has the following firewall settings:

- IMAP (TCP 143)
- POP3 (TCP 110)
- SMTP (TCP 25)
- SUBMISSION (TCP 587)
- SSMTP (TCP 465)

Anyone out there who has followed flurdy's guide and knows what the issue can be?

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine if there are any obvious firewall issues up front, try connecting to each of the application ports (143, 110, 25, etc.) via telnet from another system first and then locally on the server as needed (when there are questions as to whether the application is running).

Since Squirrel Mail is working, it may be a situation where the applications are configured to only accept local connections. In that case, that would be a firewall and/or application configuration situation.

Comment: All ports work locally when testing with telnet. Externally, all ports except 25 respond...

Comment: You might check the respective application logs to see if the external access attempts even registered. If not, then start looking at the firewall settings, otherwise the focus should be at the application settings.